# trying to get wp_get_attachment_url to output clickable link

Tags: php, images

be gentle, I'm pretty new (just over from Joomla).

This is part of an array...

```
echo '<tr><th>' . esc_html( $item_1_title ) . '</th><td>' . esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url($row['item_code1']) ) . '</td></tr>';
```

It works fine, but at the front end, the output is plain text. I can't seem to figure out how to render an encoded URL (clickable link).

Should I be using get_attachment_link or 'image source'?

Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Mark

.........

Complete php (pertinent lines; 203, 403, 463)

```
<?php
```

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/**
 * Class WC_LD_Code_Assignment
 *
 * assign codes when user pruchase a product
 */
class WC_LD_Code_Assignment {

```
public function setup() {

    // assign codes on processing or complete order status
    $delivery_order_status = get_option( 'wc_ld_delivery_order_status' );
    $order_status          = ( empty( $delivery_order_status ) ? 'completed' : $delivery_order_status );

    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_' . $order_status, array( $this, 'assign_license_codes_to_order' ), 10, 1 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', array( $this, 'display_license_codes_in_user_account' ), 10, 3 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array( $this, 'email_after_order_table' ), 100, 4 );
    add_filter( "woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock", array( $this, 'dont_reduce_order_stock' ), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', array( $this, 'manage_stock_for_simple_products' ), 100, 3 );

}

/**
 *
 * As we disabled auto stock reduction for all product
 * here, we reduce order manually for simple products
 *
 * @param $order_id
 * @param $old_status
 * @param $new_status
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function manage_stock_for_simple_products( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status ) {
    if ( is_object( $order_id ) ) {
        $order_id = $order_id->id;
    }
    // if order stock already reduced
    if ( get_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_stock_reduced', true ) ) {
        return false;
    }


    if ( $new_status == 'processing' || $new_status == 'completed' ) {
        // get the order details
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

        $order_items = $order->get_items();
        $reduced     = false;

        foreach ( $order_items as $item ) {

            $qty = $item['qty'];

            if ( $item['product_id'] > 0 ) {

                $is_license_code = get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], '_wc_ld_license_code', true );


                if ( empty( $is_license_code ) || $is_license_code == 'no' ) {


                    $_product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );


                    if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $_product->managing_stock() ) {

                            if(version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0.0', '>' )){
                                $new_stock = wc_update_product_stock($item['product_id'], $qty, 'decrease' );
                            }
                            else{
                            $new_stock = $_product->reduce_stock( $qty );
                            }

                        $item_name = $_product->get_sku() ? $_product->get_sku() : $item['product_id'];

                            if ( isset( $item['variation_id'] ) && $item['variation_id'] ) {
                                $order->add_order_note( sprintf( __( 'Item %s variation #%s stock reduced from %s to %s.', 'highthemes' ), $item_name, $item['variation_id'], $new_stock + $qty, $new_stock ) );
                            } else {
                                $order->add_order_note( sprintf( __( 'Item %s stock reduced from %s to %s.', 'highthemes' ), $item_name, $new_stock + $qty, $new_stock ) );
                            }


                        if(version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0.0', '>' )){

                        }
                        else{
                        $order->send_stock_notifications( $_product, $new_stock, $item['qty'] );
                        }
                        $reduced = true;

                    }

                }


            }
        }

        if ( $reduced ) {
            add_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_stock_reduced', '1', true );
        }
    }


}

/**
 * @return bool
 *
 * prevent payment proccessing addons to reduce stock. It is done with this plugin
 */
public function dont_reduce_order_stock( $current_value, $order ) {
    return false;
}


/**
 * @param $order
 * @param $sent_to_admin
 * @param $plain_text
 * @param $email
 *
 * included the license codes in the order email sent to the user
 */
public function email_after_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( is_object( $order ) ) {
        $delivery_order_status = get_option( 'wc_ld_delivery_order_status' );
        $order_id = $order->get_id();
        $order_status          = ( empty( $delivery_order_status ) ? 'completed' : $delivery_order_status );
        if ( $order->get_status() ==  $order_status ) {
            echo $this->get_assigned_codes( $order_id );

        }
    }

}

/**
 * @param $order_id
 *
 * get the assigned codes to an order
 *
 * @return string|void
 */
public function get_assigned_codes( $order_id ) {
    if ( is_object( $order_id ) ) {
        $order_id = $order_id->id;
    }

    // get the order details
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // check order items to get quantity and product id
    $order_items = $order->get_items();
    $codes_table = '';

    foreach ( $order_items as $key => $value ) {
        if ( ! isset( $value['license_code_ids'] ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        $license_code_ids = is_array($value['license_code_ids']) ?  $value['license_code_ids']: unserialize( $value['license_code_ids'] );

        if ( empty( $license_code_ids ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $product_id = (isset($value['variation_id']) && !empty($value['variation_id'])) ? $value['variation_id'] : $value['product_id'];
        $rows         = WC_LD_Model::get_codes_by_id( implode( ",", $license_code_ids ) );
        $code_1_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 1, $product_id );
        $code_2_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 2, $product_id );
        $code_3_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 3, $product_id );
        $code_4_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 4, $product_id );
        $code_5_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 5, $product_id );

        $description = get_post_meta( $value['product_id'], '_wc_ld_product_code_description', true );
        $codes_table .= '<h3>' . $value['name'] . '</h3>';
        $codes_table .= '<div style="padding-bottom:20px;">' . $description . '</div>';

        foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
            $codes_table .= '<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="margin-bottom:20px;width: 100%; font-family: \'Helvetica Neue\', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">';
            $codes_table .= ' <tbody>';
            if ( ! empty( $row['license_code1'] ) ) {
                $codes_table .= '<tr><th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;width:40%; background-color:#eeeeee;">' . esc_html( $code_1_title ) . '</th><td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">' . esc_html( $row['license_code1'] ) . '</td></tr>';
            }

            if ( ! empty( $row['license_code2'] ) ) {
                $codes_table .= '<tr><th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">' . esc_html( $code_2_title ) . '</th><td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">' . esc_html( $row['license_code2'] ) . '</td></tr>';
            }

            if ( ! empty( $row['license_code3'] ) ) {
                $codes_table .= '<tr><th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">' . esc_html( $code_3_title ) . '</th><td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">' . esc_html( $row['license_code3'] ) . '</td></tr>';
            }

            if ( ! empty( $row['license_code4'] ) ) {
                $codes_table .= '<tr><th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">' . esc_html( $code_4_title ) . '</th><td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">' . esc_html( $row['license_code4'] ) . '</td></tr>';
            }
            if ( ! empty( $row['license_code5'] ) ) {
                $codes_table .= '<tr><th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">' . esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url($code_5_title) ) . '</th><td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">' . esc_html( $row['license_code5'] ) . '</td></tr>';
            }
            $codes_table .= '</tbody></table>';


        }


    }

    return $codes_table;

}

/**
 * @param $order_id
 *
 * do the license code assignment to order
 */
public function assign_license_codes_to_order( $order_id ) {

    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_object( $order_id ) ) {
        $order_id = $order_id->id;
    }

    // get the order details
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // check order items to get quantity and product id
    $order_items = $order->get_items();


    // assign license codes to order items
    foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {

        // if there is no code assigned to this order item
        if ( empty( $item['license_code_ids'] ) ) {

            // if product has marked as license code product
            $is_license_code = get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], '_wc_ld_license_code', true );
            if ( empty( $is_license_code ) || $is_license_code == 'no' ) {
                continue;
            }
            $this->assign_license_to_item( $item_id, $item, $order, $order_id );

        }


    }


}

/**
 * @param $item_id
 * @param $item
 * @param $order
 * @param $order_id
 *
 * does the license assignment for each order item
 */
public function assign_license_to_item( $item_id, $item, $order, $order_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $product_id = (isset($item['variation_id']) && !empty($item['variation_id'])) ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'];
    $qty        = $item['qty'];

    // get license codes from databse based on requested qty
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->wc_ld_license_codes}
                WHERE product_id = $product_id
                AND license_code1 <> ''
                AND license_status = '0'
                LIMIT $qty" );

    // build an array of license code ids
    foreach ( $rows as $query ) {
        $license_code_ids[] = $query->id;
    }
    // only assign license codes if we have the requested quantity of the item
    if ( count( $license_code_ids ) == $qty ) {

        // save the order id in license codes table
        $this->assign_order_id_to_license_codes( $order_id, $license_code_ids );

        // save the assigned license codes in order item meta
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_license_code_ids', $license_code_ids );

        // change sold license codes status to sold
        WC_LD_Model::change_license_codes_status( implode( $license_code_ids, ',' ), '1' );


        // reduce stock

        $_product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );

        if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $_product->managing_stock() ) {

                if(version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0.0', '>' ) ){
                    $new_stock = wc_update_product_stock($product_id , $qty, 'decrease' );
                    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_stock_reduced', '1', true );
                }
                else{
                    $new_stock = $_product->reduce_stock( $qty );
                    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_stock_reduced', '1', true );
                }

            $item_name = $_product->get_sku() ? $_product->get_sku() : $item['product_id'];

            if ( isset( $item['variation_id'] ) && $item['variation_id'] ) {
                $order->add_order_note( sprintf( __( 'Item %s variation #%s stock reduced from %s to %s.',
                    'highthemes' ), $item_name, $item['variation_id'], $new_stock + $qty, $new_stock ) );
            } else {
                $order->add_order_note( sprintf( __( 'Item %s stock reduced from %s to %s.',
                    'highthemes' ),
                    $item_name, $new_stock + $qty, $new_stock ) );
            }

            if(version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0.0', '>' )){
            }
            else{
                $order->send_stock_notifications( $_product, $new_stock, $item['qty'] );
            }
        }


    } else {
        $order->add_order_note( sprintf( __( 'Not enough license code available for product <strong>%s</strong>.',
            'highthemes' ),
            $item['name'] ), 1, false );
    }


}

/**
 * @param $order_id
 * @param $license_code_ids
 *
 * saves order id into license codes table for later usages
 */
public function assign_order_id_to_license_codes( $order_id, $license_code_ids ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( "UPDATE {$wpdb->wc_ld_license_codes} SET order_id=$order_id
                            WHERE id IN (" . implode( $license_code_ids, ',' ) . ")" );

}

/**
 * @param $item_id
 * @param $item
 * @param $order
 *
 * displays the purchased license codes in my account page
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function display_license_codes_in_user_account( $item_id, $item, $order ) {

    if ( ! is_account_page() && !is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( empty( $item['license_code_ids'] ) ) {
        return false;
    }


    $license_code_ids = is_array( $item['license_code_ids']) ?  $item['license_code_ids']:unserialize( $item['license_code_ids'] );
    $rows             = WC_LD_Model::get_codes_by_id( implode( ",", $license_code_ids ) );
    $product_id = (isset($item['variation_id']) && !empty($item['variation_id'])) ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'];
    $code_1_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 1, $product_id );
    $code_2_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 2, $product_id );
    $code_3_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 3, $product_id );
    $code_4_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 4, $product_id );
    $code_5_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 5, $product_id );


    // checking the user capability
    echo '<table class="license-codes-table" style="width:100%;">';
    echo ' <tbody>';
    foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
        echo '';
        if ( ! empty( $row['license_code1'] ) ) {
            echo '<tr><th>' . esc_html( $code_1_title ) . '</th><td>' . esc_html( $row['license_code1'] ) . '</td></tr>';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $row['license_code2'] ) ) {
            echo '<tr><th>' . esc_html( $code_2_title ) . '</th><td>' . esc_html( $row['license_code2'] ) . '</td></tr>';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $row['license_code3'] ) ) {
            echo '<tr><th>' . esc_html( $code_3_title ) . '</th><td>' . esc_html( $row['license_code3'] ) . '</td></tr>';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $row['license_code4'] ) ) {
            echo '<tr><th>' . esc_html( $code_4_title ) . '</th><td>' . esc_html( $row['license_code4'] ) . '</td></tr>';
        }
        if ( ! empty( $row['license_code5'] ) ) {
            echo '<tr><th>' . esc_html( $code_5_title ) . '</th><td>' . esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url($row['license_code5']) ) . '</td></tr>';
        }
        echo '<tr class="order-gap"><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>';

    }


    echo '</tbody></table>';
}

/**
 * @param $item_id
 * @param $item
 * @param $order
 *
 * displays the purchased license codes in my account page
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function display_license_codes( $item ) {
    //echo $this->get_assigned_codes(15);
    $license_ids=wc_get_order_item_meta( $item->get_id(), '_license_code_ids' );    
    if ( empty( $license_ids ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    //$license_code_ids=$license_ids;
    $license_code_ids = is_array( $license_ids)
        ? $license_ids
        : unserialize( $license_ids );

    $rows = WC_LD_Model::get_codes_by_id( implode( ",", $license_code_ids ) );
    $product_id = (isset($item['variation_id']) && !empty($item['variation_id']))  ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'];
    $code_1_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 1, $product_id);
    $code_2_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 2, $product_id );
    $code_3_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 3, $product_id );
    $code_4_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 4, $product_id );
    $code_5_title = WC_LD_Model::get_code_title( 5, $product_id );


    // checking the user capability
    echo '<table class="license-codes-table" style="width:100%;">';
    echo ' <tbody>';
    foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
        echo '';
        if ( ! empty( $row['license_code1'] ) ) {
            echo '<tr><th>' . esc_html( $code_1_title ) . '</th><td>' . esc_html( $row['license_code1'] ) . '</td></tr>';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $row['license_code2'] ) ) {
            echo '<tr><th>' . esc_html( $code_2_title ) . '</th><td>' . esc_html( $row['license_code2'] ) . '</td></tr>';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $row['license_code3'] ) ) {
            echo '<tr><th>' . esc_html( $code_3_title ) . '</th><td>' . esc_html( $row['license_code3'] ) . '</td></tr>';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $row['license_code4'] ) ) {
            echo '<tr><th>' . esc_html( $code_4_title ) . '</th><td>' . esc_html( $row['license_code4'] ) . '</td></tr>';
        }
        if ( ! empty( $row['license_code5'] ) ) {
            echo '<tr><th>' . esc_html( $code_5_title ) . '</th><td>' . esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url($row['license_code5']) ) . '</td></tr>';
        }
        echo '<tr class="order-gap"><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>';

    }


    echo '</tbody></table>';
}


/**
 * @param $code
 *
 * this function used to mask license codes
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function mask_license_code( $code ) {


    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce' ) ) {
        if ( strlen( $code ) <= 4 ) {
            $padsize = 2;
            $n       = - 2;
        } else {
            $padsize = strlen( $code ) - 4;
            $n       = - 4;
        }

        return str_repeat( '*', $padsize ) . substr( $code, $n );
    } else {
        return $code;

    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You're onto the answer...

The function, `wp_get_attachment_url()` (see [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)) just gives you the URL. You could wrap it in a link:

```
echo '<tr><td><a href="' . esc_attr(wp_get_attachment_url($row['item_code1'])) . '">' . esc_html($item_1_title) . '</a></td></tr>';
```

Alternately, you can use `wp_get_attachment_link()` (see [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link)) as you mentioned:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_link($row['item_code1'], 'medium', false, false, esc_html($item_1_title));
```

Neither is specifically better all the time, it'll depend on what you're doing.

Keep in mind that if you use the first bit of code above, your `<a>` tag *should* have an `alt` attribute. I believe this is for accessibility. You could use the link text, wrapped in `esc_attr()` for this.

**Updated** (after added code module)

I've looked at your code.

I must be missing something because I don't see anywhere it's rendering `<a>` tags. Going with what you're saying, that they're rendered in the front-end HTML, I'd have to *guess* that someone somewhere has some filter that's modifying what `esc_url()` does.

Looking at the [core code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L4171) (line 4171), there's one filter, `clean_url`, that's applied to the output of `esc_url()` before it returns. It's messy and poor according to WP best practices, but I've seen worse than someone editing that to do something like this. You'd probably have to do a text search on the code base (probably `wp-content/plugins`, although that could be a lot of code) to find if there's an instance of this filter being hooked. My spidey sense tells me that this isn't the place to start though.

Not to be snarky, and I mean this in the most straightforward way, but I'm not completely sure I understand what you're saying is going wrong. I *think* you mean that the browser is rendering something like this:

```
<td>
    <a href="http://domain.com/path-to-something">http://domain.com/path-to-something</a>
</td>
```

That would seem like the right output *to me,* but you're asking this question because the output isn't right *to you.* This leads me to believe that I don't fully understand the question, reinforced by the fact that I don't understand the thing about pasting a URL into a text box.

Could you maybe edit with a snippet of HTML as rendered, and a snippet of HTML as you *want* it rendered? Given the code you posted, I could try to reconcile the two and see what's going on.

**Updated** (let's try this)

For starters, welcome to WordPress. Also welcome to WP SE.

(Your code doesn't show in your post with line numbers so please bear with me.)

In the function, `get_assigned_codes`, try changing this line:

```
$codes_table .= '<tr><th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">' . esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url($code_5_title) ) . '</th><td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">' . esc_html( $row['license_code5'] ) . '</td></tr>';
```

(it's the third-to-last line in the function that isn't whitespace or curlies) with this:

```
$codes_table .= '<tr><th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><a href="' . esc_attr(esc_url(wp_get_attachment_url($code_5_title))) . '">' . esc_url(wp_get_attachment_url($code_5_title)) . '</a></th><td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">' . esc_html( $row['license_code5'] ) . '</td></tr>';
```

To see if that works, you'll have to go to the right place that uses that function and compare the output.

There appear to be a few other places where it's doing about the same thing (hence why you referenced several code lines) but let's try one to see what it does.

If you try that, do you get more of what you want?

**Updating** (a bit more info but we're onto something)

Try this:

```
$codes_table .= '<tr><th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">' . esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url($code_5_title) ) . '</th><td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><a href="' . esc_attr( $row['license_code5'] ) . '">' . esc_html($row['license_code5']) . '</a>&nbsp;<a href="' . esc_attr(wp_get_attachment_url($row['license_code5'])) . '">' . esc_html($row['license_code5']) . '</a></td></tr>';
```

My apologies, the previous suggestion was incorrect. I put the change in the wrong place.

This should print 2 items in the URL field. If either of them is correct, remove the incorrect one and the extra stuff around it. Also, you probably don't need `wp_get_attachment_url()` in the left-hand field.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks very much for the support... The solution worked (kind of) as expected, but on the front end, it's just pulling in the full href, it still won't generate a clickable link... Might it have something to do with charset, or the formatting of the SQL column? - I'm just guessing here. - FYI, the URL in question is just an image uploaded through a pretty typical CMS-type event (adding a product to an inventory), it just seems weird that it's behaviour is so restricted at the front end. - Thanks again

Comment: What's it doing on the front end? Can you take a look at the source HTML and see if it's outputting an `<a>` tag at all? If it's an encoding issue, you can take care of a lot of that with `esc_attr()`, or you may need to use some of the `mb_` functions.

Comment: To spare you a life story, it's a WooCommerce order 'details' page... It's a site that sells license codes. - At the front end the HTML is rendering the full HREF (including <a> tags) - I've tried various methods, but it's like trying to paste a link into a plain text field, it just doesn't render. - I've attached the whole module php on my original post... I don't for one minute expect you to go through it in detail, I'm just hoping it might provide a frame of reference (apologies for the impromptu 'break', I think it's because the comment-out is a bit weird) . Thanks so much for your time

Comment: Updated, the code looks like it's doing something different than what you say the output looks like. I'm clearly missing something, hopefully we can get to what that is.

Comment: Many apologies if I'm not explaining myself properly... Here's an image of the front end http://www.domsdailydeals.com/screenshot.png    - You'll notice the URL for the image file is called in the 3rd custom field (generated by the plug in). I'm just looking to make this clickable, but maybe there's a filter issue with wp_get_link or something. It's a bit of a mystery, considering, in principle anyway, it should be a pretty basic hack.

Comment: Additionally. Thank you most sincerely for spending so much of your time, helping me to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: *Note - You probably didn't see the <a> tags in there because I copied it over 'as per original', not after I'd been tweaking with esc_attr etc etc

Comment: Hmm... not seeing the `<a>` tags. Could be a copy problem. Try from the last update? I think we may be talking about different things, that should help clear it up. Happy to help.

Comment: *Further explanation* There were originally no <a> tags. I tried adding them in post using the method you suggested. The code above is how it came from the publisher, I'm just looking to amend it so I can get a rendered link in the front end... Hope this clears it up.

Comment: I replaced the line as suggested and it does exactly what it used to (on the front end anyway). It displays the URL, but only in plain text.

Comment: I'll try replacing the other instances and see what happens

Comment: Here's my findings.. First, let's make sure we're operating from the same statistical base. There's 3 instances in the code, where similar functions are called;  I'll reference the 'first one' as the block that has style information attached to it. - So I tried that and nothing happened at all. I then removed the style 'stuff' so it was more in-keeping with the other instances...

Comment: and something did happen, I lost the field 'title' and for some reason, the random number '584' appeared in the column, see https://domsdailydeals.com/Screenshot2.png This happened when I replaced the line on the 'second' instance (but left the first 'as is') and also when I applied the change to all 3 instances.

Comment: Gaa... yup. I put the wrong thing in the right place. Gonna need to try a couple more things. One moment, I'll edit.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest. The woocommerce 'wrapper' that this plug-in's output is contained within, DOES manage to render links properly, but having looked at the code, they have filters applied, like: echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $product_permalink ? sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $product_permalink, $item->get_name() ) : $item->get_name(), $item, $is_visible );  I hope I don't have to go down this route, it's all Chinese to me.

Comment: OK, now things are looking interesting... Here's the screenshot: www.domsdailydeals.com/Screenshot3.png and yes, there are two URL items and the second one works, although I've still lost the title and the link content is a weird random number, but that's so awesome, I was beginning to lose hope on this one... I'll have a play with the line ordering to see if I can get it perfect.

Comment: I posted another answer that's a little more teach-to-fish than give-a-fish. Maybe that'll be better.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer wasn't helping. Let me approach this a different way that may be of some use to someone in the future.

**You're coming from Joomla.** It's been forever since I used it but Google tells me it's based on PHP. WP is somewhat object-oriented but I've seen more non-object-oriented plugins than I've seen object-oriented ones.

So you've got a basis in PHP.

**A filter** is a thing that lets you modify things at runtime. Filter names are ephemeral but core [uses a whole bunch of them](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference). You hook using [`add_filter()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) with a priority and a number of arguments. The return value of a filter is always supposed to be of the same type as the first argument, thereby making the remaining arguments modifiers for how the filter is supposed to work. Also, if you call a filter (using [`apply_filters()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)) and there are no filters defined, it'll just give you back your argument. `add_action()` does the same thing without returning a value (PHP void).

**The `wp_posts` table** contains stuff. Some CMS systems do it differently but many just use a big flat table like this. The `post_type` column tells you what kind of post it is, with `post` (re-use of the name) being a blog and `page` being a front-end page. You can [define custom post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). Additional metadata about a post is stored in `wp_postmeta`, using the post ID.

(Tables are prefixed and your prefix may not be `wp_`. The suffix is the same.)

[`wp_get_attachment_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) **takes a post ID** and returns the URL of a post of `post_type` `attachment` that's associated with that post. (Therefore, `attachment` is another core post type.) It returns just the URL, not a link. If you want a link, you have to either use [`wp_get_attachment_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link) or draw the link yourself. That's something like this:

```
?>
    <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_link($id); ?>">link text</a>
<?php
```

I'm not sure which of your variables contains the post ID and which contains the text to display. This is based on how WooCommerce is set up. In WC (it appears as if you're in Europe so please excuse the abbreviation), products are stored as posts. I forgot the exact `post_type` and I don't have a WC setup handy. Therefore, you're probably looking for the post ID for a product.

**You can use direct database access** to get things using [the `wpdb` class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) but the way you're, "supposed to," do it is with [the `WP_Query` class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Instantiate one with an array like so:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'product', 'nopaging' => true));
```

Then use `$query->posts` to get an array of the matched records.

**The helper functions** [`esc_html()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html) and [`esc_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) escape text for output for element content and attributes, respectively. [`esc_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) is similar. As with any other CMS, never trust anything that comes from the user (even an admin) or the database. These functions help you wrap it.

**You can debug** using `printf()`. `print_r()` works for arrays and objects. I prefer `var_export($object, true)` because it always pretty-prints everything. If you can set up your PHP log, `error_log()` works well (that's what I use). I've never found an IDE that really helps me debug well enough.

That having been said, you're dumping data into an HTML table. Find out (using some debugging method) what your post ID is and what text you want to display. Then use `wp_get_attachment_url()` with your post ID to get the URL of the image you want to display. If `$id` has the post ID and `$linktext` has the link text, do this:

```
echo '<a href="' . esc_attr(wp_get_attachment_url($id)) . '">' . $linktext . '</a>';
```

Stick that somewhere into a `<th>` or `<td>` and you'll get a clickable link. If you want to display the image, do this:

```
echo '<img src="' . esc_attr(wp_get_attachment_url($id)) . '" />';
```

Hopefully, somewhere in there is all you need to get this to work.

Comment: You're nothing short of a superstar, thank you.